# Maclaurin Expansion Implementation Using python giving two different answers for two different logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

To find sin(1.2) using Maclaurin expansion, I wrote the following code:

```
import math as m
N = 25
k=1
s=x
sign = 1

while k<N:
    sign = -sign

    k = k + 2

    term = sign*x**k/m.factorial(k)

    s = s + term

print(s)
```

It Works fine and gives 0.9320390859672263

Then my brother wrote it as:

```
x=1.2
s=x
i = 3
flag=0

while(i < 25):
    if(flag==1):
        s += (x**i)/(m.factorial(i))
        flag=0
    if(flag==0):
        s -= (x**i)/(m.factorial(i))
        flag=1
    i += 2

print(s)
```

And the answer was 0.9119999999999999

Both are the same logic, but answer is different. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second version, when `flag` is 1, you set it equal to 0 and then immediately test it again. Since `flag` is now 0, you end up executing both branches of the if statement:

```
while(i < 25):
    if(flag==1):  # Flag is initially set to 1, so this is True
        s += (x**i)/(m.factorial(i))
        flag=0  # Flag is now set to 0
    if(flag==0):  # Flag just became 0, so this is now True!
        s -= (x**i)/(m.factorial(i))  # This undoes the first calculation
        flag=1
    i += 2

print(s)
```

As a result, the code only updates `s` when `flag` is 0, and effectively does nothing when `flag` is 1. This can be fixed by using `else` or `elif` to make sure only one branch of the if statement is executed each time through the loop:

```
while(i < 25):
    if(flag==1):
        s += (x**i)/(m.factorial(i))
        flag=0
    else:  # This avoids comparing flag a second time
        s -= (x**i)/(m.factorial(i))
        flag=1
    i += 2
```

This gives the same value as your first approach.